# reactjs.net Thread was being aborted

Tags: c#, reactjs, iis-10, reactjs.net, chakracore

We've developed our code using Ractjs 3, JavaScriptEngineSwitcher, and Microsoft.ChakraCore.

Once in a while my application took some seconds to load a page but I didn't have any errors on my application log so I decided to diagnose it with DebugDiag tools on windows server. Then I found several ThreadAbortException related to Chakra.

> System.Threading.ThreadAbortException
>
> Thread was being aborted
>
> System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOneNative(System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle, UInt32, Boolean, Boolean) 
>      System.Threading.WaitHandle.InternalWaitOne(System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle, Int64, Boolean, Boolean) 
>      System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne(Int32, Boolean) 
>      JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.ChakraCore.ScriptDispatcher.StartThread() 
>      System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) 
>      System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) 
>      System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object) 
>      System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

20% of all threads have:.

**Entry point   ChakraCore!JsDisposeRuntime+12a44**

**Call Stack**

ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+14

KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+ef

ChakraCore+bd824

ChakraCore!JsDisposeRuntime+26ee

ChakraCore!JsDisposeRuntime+12aa1

kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+14

ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+21

Also another 20% have:

**Entry point   ChakraCore!JsDisposeRuntime+12a44**

**Call Stack**

ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+14

KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+ef

ChakraCore!JsGetPropertyIdFromName+1673

ChakraCore!JsGetPropertyIdFromName+1410

ChakraCore!JsGetPropertyIdFromName+993

ChakraCore!JsDisposeRuntime+12aa1

kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+14

ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+21

Comment: Is this error still relevant?

Answer (score 0):

Are you correctly adding references to JavaScriptValues that you are processing on the native side? If not, you'll have memory corruption of which one of the symptoms would be crashes on disposal of the ChakraCore context/runtime.

For an example of how to guard against this class of issues, see [React Native Windows' real-world example of how to safely embed ChakraCore](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-windows/blob/master/ReactWindows/ReactNative.Shared/Chakra/Executor/ChakraJavaScriptExecutor.cs#L118) (while still being performant).